# Button onclick is fired when page loads

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and am trying to create a Chrome extension that get recenf nfl scores. I have added two buttons, but they are being clicked as soon as the extension loads. Why is this happening? I have added my EventListeners below.

```
document.getElementById("reg").addEventListener("click",inter("http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml"));
document.getElementById("post").addEventListener("click",inter("http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/postseason/ss.xml"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your `inter` function inside a function block:

```
document.getElementById("reg").addEventListener("click",function() {inter("http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml")});
```

Otherwise it is executed while the browser parses it.